# Insert record from dataframe into MySQL table using Spark / java

Tags: java, mysql, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe :

```
+------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+---+------+--------------------+-----------+
|   id_alerte|id_type|      tracking_time|ID_tracking|vue|    id|         observation|id_vehicule|
+------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+---+------+--------------------+-----------+
|188978561024|      9|2020-02-19 09:20:54|  900100393|  0|100491|LE VEHICULE A ARR...|     997801|
+------------+-------+-------------------+-----------+---+------+--------------------+-----------+
```

My database table :

```
+------------------+-------------+
|id_alertePrimaire | int(11)     |
+------------------+-------------+      
|  id_alerte       | int P_K     |
|  id_type         | int(11)     |      
| dateAlerte       | timestamp   |          
| id_tracking      | bigint(20)  |                  
| vue              | tinyint(1)  |          
| id_alert_prog    | int(11)     |              
| observation      | varchar(255)|          
| id_vehicule      |  int(11)    |
+------------------+-------------+
```

I want to save this record on a MaySQL table

The code I'm using is :

```
data.write().format("jdbc").option("url", "myurl")
                             .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                             .option("dbtable", "alerte").option("user", "root").option("password", "").mode("append");
```

**I get no error but nothing is added to the database table**

If you have any idea
I would be very thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing string **`"myurl"`** string instead of variable value `mysql`.

Try with **`myurl`** in option (or) keep your jdbc url as hard coded **`<jdbc:mysql>...`**

```
data.write().format("jdbc").option("url", myurl)
                             .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                             .option("dbtable", "alerte").option("user", "root").option("password", "").mode("append");
```